# Flannel pod failure (and DNS) for Kubernetes on CoreOS VMs

Tags: kubernetes, kube-dns, kube-proxy

I have deployed a 3-node CoreOS Vagrant VMs following [this guide](https://medium.com/@kasun.dsilva/setup-kubernetes-on-coreos-f801e6db8dec), modified as described [here](https://github.com/massenz/k8s-coreos).

The VMs are healthy and running; K8s controller/worker nodes are fine; and I can deploy Pods; ReplicaSets; etc.

However, DNS does not seem to work and, when I look at the state of the `flannel` pods, they are positively unhealthy:

```
$ kubectl get po --all-namespaces                          
NAMESPACE     NAME                                   READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
apps          frontend-cluster-q4gvm                 1/1       Running            1          1h
apps          frontend-cluster-tl5ts                 1/1       Running            0          1h
apps          frontend-cluster-xgktz                 1/1       Running            1          1h
kube-system   kube-apiserver-172.17.8.101            1/1       Running            2          32d
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-172.17.8.101   1/1       Running            2          32d
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-6csjl                  0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   46         31d
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-f8czg                  0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   48         31d
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-qbtlc                  0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   52         31d
kube-system   kube-proxy-172.17.8.101                1/1       Running            2          32d
kube-system   kube-proxy-172.17.8.102                1/1       Running            0          6m
kube-system   kube-proxy-172.17.8.103                1/1       Running            0          2m
kube-system   kube-scheduler-172.17.8.101            1/1       Running            2          32d
```

further, when I try to deploy `kubedns` those fail too, with the same failure mode:

```
$ kubectl logs kube-flannel-ds-f8czg -n kube-system        
I0608 23:03:32.526331       1 main.go:475] Determining IP address of default interface
I0608 23:03:32.528108       1 main.go:488] Using interface with name eth0 and address 10.0.2.15
I0608 23:03:32.528135       1 main.go:505] Defaulting external address to interface address (10.0.2.15)
E0608 23:04:02.627348       1 main.go:232] Failed to create SubnetManager: error retrieving pod spec for 'kube-system/kube-flannel-ds-f8czg': Get https://10.3.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/kube-flannel-ds-f8czg: dial tcp 10.3.0.1:443: i/o timeout
```

So, it appears that the controller service, running off the `10.3.0.1` IP is not reachable from other pods:

```
$ kubectl get svc --all-namespaces 
NAMESPACE   NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
apps        frontend     ClusterIP   10.3.0.170   <none>        80/TCP,443/TCP   1h
default     kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.3.0.1     <none>        443/TCP          32d
```

My guess were around either Flannel's `etcd` configurations; or the `kube-proxy` YAML; so, I added the following to all the nodes:

```
core@core-01 ~ $ etcdctl ls /flannel/network/subnets
/flannel/network/subnets/10.1.80.0-24
/flannel/network/subnets/10.1.76.0-24
/flannel/network/subnets/10.3.0.0-16
/flannel/network/subnets/10.1.34.0-24

core@core-01 ~ $ etcdctl get /flannel/network/subnets/10.3.0.0-16
{"PublicIP": "172.17.8.101"}
```

and restarted `flanneld`:

```
core@core-01 ~ $ sudo systemctl restart flanneld
```

However, that does not appear to do any good; from within a running Pod:

```
# This is expected (no client certs):
root@frontend-cluster-q4gvm:/opt/simple# curl -k https://172.17.8.101/api/v1/pods
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "Unauthorized",
  "reason": "Unauthorized",
  "code": 401
}
# But this one just times out:
root@frontend-cluster-q4gvm:/opt/simple# curl -k https://10.3.0.1/api/v1/pods
```

Then I looked into the `kube-proxy.yaml` and suspected that the `--master` configuration (for the worker nodes) was not correct, somehow?

```
core@core-02 /etc/kubernetes/manifests $ cat kube-proxy.yaml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kube-proxy
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  hostNetwork: true
  containers:
  - name: kube-proxy
    image: quay.io/coreos/hyperkube:v1.10.1_coreos.0
    command:
    - /hyperkube
    - proxy
>>>>> Should it be like this?
    - --master=https://172.17.8.101
>>>>> or like this?
    - --master=http://127.0.0.1:8080

    securityContext:
      privileged: true
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
      name: ssl-certs-host
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /usr/share/ca-certificates
    name: ssl-certs-host
```

the `127.0.0.1:8080` configuration would appear to work only (at best) for the controller node, but would surely lead nowhere on the other nodes?

Modifying the `--master` as indicated above and restarting the pods however, does not do any good either.

Bottom line is, how do I make the Controller API reachable on `10.3.0.1`?
How can I enable KubeDNS (I tried the instructions on the "Hard Way" guide, but got exactly the same failure mode as above).

Many thanks in advance!

**Update**

This is the file with the `flanneld` options:

```
$ cat /etc/flannel/options.env 
FLANNELD_IFACE=172.17.8.101
FLANNELD_ETCD_ENDPOINTS=http://172.17.8.102:2379,http://172.17.8.103:2379,http://172.17.8.101:2379
```

I have now removed the flannel daemon set:

```
kc delete ds kube-flannel-ds -n kube-system
```

and deployed Kube DNS, following these instructions: the service is defined [here](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/818501707e418fc4d6e6aedef8395ca368e3097e/services/kubedns.yaml), and the deployment [here](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/818501707e418fc4d6e6aedef8395ca368e3097e/deployments/kubedns.yaml):

```
$ kc -n kube-system get svc
NAME       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
kube-dns   ClusterIP   10.3.0.10    <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   4d


$ kc get po -n kube-system  
NAME                                   READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-apiserver-172.17.8.101            1/1       Running   5          36d
kube-controller-manager-172.17.8.101   1/1       Running   5          36d
kube-dns-7868b65c7b-ntc95              3/4       Running   2          3m
kube-proxy-172.17.8.101                1/1       Running   5          36d
kube-proxy-172.17.8.102                1/1       Running   3          4d
kube-proxy-172.17.8.103                1/1       Running   2          4d
kube-scheduler-172.17.8.101            1/1       Running   5          36d
```

However, I'm still getting the timeout error (actually, a bunch of them):

```
E0613 19:02:27.193691       1 sync.go:105] Error getting ConfigMap kube-system:kube-dns err: Get https://10.3.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/kube-dns: dial tcp 10.3.0.1:443: i/o timeout
```

**Update #2**

On a system setup similarly, I have the following `flanneld` configuration:

```
core@core-02 ~ $ etcdctl get /flannel/network/config
{ "Network": "10.1.0.0/16" }
core@core-02 ~ $ etcdctl ls /flannel/network/subnets
/flannel/network/subnets/10.1.5.0-24
/flannel/network/subnets/10.1.66.0-24
/flannel/network/subnets/10.1.6.0-24
core@core-02 ~ $ etcdctl get /flannel/network/subnets/10.1.66.0-24
{"PublicIP":"172.17.8.102"}
```

(and similarly for the others, pointing to `101` and `103`) - should there be something in `config` for the `10.3.0.0/16` subnet?
Also, should there be an entry (pointing to to `172.17.8.101`) for the Controller API at `10.3.0.1`? 
Something along the lines of:

```
/flannel/network/subnets/10.3.0.0-24
{"PublicIP":"172.17.8.101"}
```

Does anyone know where to find good `flanneld` documentation (CoreOS docs are truly insufficient and feel somewhat "abandoned")? 
Or something else to use that actually works?

Thanks!

Comment: [Marco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1263473/marco), according to the instructions from the links provided in your post, you use flannel as a daemon. But you also have flannel pods with errors which you are trying to solve. You need to use only one type of flannel configuration, possibly after that, kube-dns will work fine. Also, could you provide configuration from `/etc/flannel/options.env` file?

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaev thanks for pointing it out: my (naive) assumption was that both were needed for flannel to work in the Pods.  Removing the Pods, did not help much (see my update); I was thinking of stopping the service, and run the DaemonSet instead: do you think that would be worth trying?

Comment: [Marco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1263473/marco) could you provide log for Flannel daemon?

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaev - see the file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zxeuvz14kzojde6/flanneld.logs?dl=0) - thanks!

Comment: [Marco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1263473/marco), I only can suggest you to try to use Kubernetes DaemonSet for Flannel instead of OS daemon, here is the [example](https://github.com/coreos/flannel/blob/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml). Don't forget to stop daemon and remove configuration for Flannel from etcd